# How can I uninstall Oracle 11g from Windows?

Tags: oracle-11g

When I try to uninstall Oracle 11g from Windows, I get the following error message:

> Checking swap space: 0 MB available, 500 MB required.

How can I fix this to completely uninstall Oracle 11g?

Comment: "How can I uninstall Oracle 11g from Windows?" "With a lot of luck and/or a disk format."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into this problem before on a machine where windows was managing the swap space.  Oracle, thinking it's smarter than windows, seems to require you to have your swap space discretely allocated.  You can do that by following the steps below.

How to:

Right click on my computer > properties > advanced
In the Performance section click on 'Settings' and find the Advanced Tab
In the Advanced tab, find the Virtual Memory section and click on change
Select a drive with disk space available and add provide a min and max size

I usually go with a setting that's 2x my RAM for both the Min and Max - windows chews up a lot of cycles trying to grow the swap file.

Comment: great! that worked (i didn't even have to reboot my machine ..)

Answer (score 0):

A descriptive solution is given in http://arjudba.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-uninstall-oracle-11g.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Oracle software 11.2g

In 11.2g there is deinstall command through which you can uninstall standalone Oracle Database installations, Oracle Clusterware and Automatic Storage Management (ASM) from your server, as well as Oracle Real Application Clusters (Oracle RAC) and Oracle Database client installations. You can find out deinstall tool under $ORACLE_HOME/deinstall folder.If you don’t have deinstall tool you can download it from url http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/database/index.html- Under Oracle Database 11g Release 2, click See All for the respective platform for which you want to download the Deinstallation Tool.

- The Deinstallation Tool is available for download at the end of the page.So, in 11.2g just use,
  $$ORACLE_HOME/deinstall/deinstall

  1. Here are the steps you need to follow for Deinstalling Oracle 11g.
  2. Unzip the Deinstall Toll file set just downloaded and copy it over to any directory you want.
  3. Open command prompt(Run as Administrator) Windows>Start>Run.
  4. Set you ORACLE_HOME to the Home which you want to deinstall using this command set ORACLE_HOME = c:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1
  5. Type deinstall –home c:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1